# Get the current ringer volume value in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, audio, volume

I would imagine this is fairly simple but I haven't had any luck with it. I'm looking for the simplest way to find out what the current ringer volume is.

I want to add an if statement that checks for a minimum volume level, but it's specifically to do with the volume of push notification alerts, hence why I need to check the ringer volume and not the volume of a mediaplayer or audioplayer object.

The push sound is played using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)` but I can't see any corresponding functions to change or check the volume.

Comment: Any luck in getting this?

Comment: Afraid not, in the end I just gave up as it wasn't critical.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue - I tried looking in the Apple docs for a list of preferences to query. Perhaps it's not something queried using AudioServices. Is there even an unexposed property that we're not meant to access, that may be rejected by the approval process? It'd be nice to see that even to understand that Apple haven't exposed this option.

It's pretty difficult to search for, as similar results for things like System volume (which is different) and general iOS user help keep cropping up! And yup, I've tried looking through the dev site documentation.

Thanks